# How can I output the body of a webpage if the response code is 500 using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I've been through hell and high water with this problem.  I get a 500 error on a page a tiny, tiny fraction of the time.  I have been completely unable to reproduce it, but Google insists that they see a 500 code.  Fetch as Googlebot says it's successful, however something is wrong.  I've been down many avenues and the only recourse I have left is to brute-force the local copy of the website.

I want to use curl to hammer the dev site until I get a 500 error, and when I do, to output the body of the page to the terminal so I can actually get some useful information.

```
for(;;){
    $url = "http://www.blahblah.dev/";

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //Enable curl response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //Enable POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    //Use the $pData array as the POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jData);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(strstr($result, "error")){
        echo $result;
        exit();
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    usleep(500000);
}
```

As you can see, I'm simply checking to see if "error" appears in the body, as I can't figure out how to check for a 500 error properly.  I realize that this is a terrible and contrived way of debugging, but it's all I've got at this point.  Thanks!

Comment: You should check the error log of the web-server instead.

Comment: Strangely, I can't find anything in the logs with regards to a 500 error in the past few days.  I'm not sure if there's a configuration error or what, but something's goofy and I can't find any trace of the error.  I do, however, see the 500 errors in the access log.  Just nothing about it in the error log.  It's very strange.

Comment: That is very strange. However, I don't think your curl will show you anything when a 500 is sent.

Comment: Well according to the access logs, every 500 response contain ~750 bytes (whereas a successful response is a few thousand), which would lead me to believe that an actual error page, possibly containing useful information, is displayed to the user.  I would think that the small size would indicate that some error is displayed.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

66.249.75.242 - - [04/Jan/2013:10:29:06 -0600] "GET /blah/details/21585/this-is-a-url HTTP/1.1" 500 752 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"